# I have a problem when I was installing flutter

Tags: android, flutter, installation

please help me I do all steps for install flutter , I installed VSC program and jdk and android studio but when I was installing android studio it say you don't have SDK I took  some photos you can see it to help me[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xK0fE.png)

Answer (score 1):

Install android sdk from
Android sdk> More Action >Sdk Manager> Android sdk> (click latest version of android sdk and apply )

Comment: I completed install android when I go into sdk manager it wrote "The Android SDK location cannot be at filesystem root" I replace the location of sdk but it give me the same message

Comment: all button disable

Comment: you have give to path where sdk is located .